# Annotation for simple inheritance on Doctrine2

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, orm

can u help me with simple inheritance on Doctrine2?

I have basic class for all users:

```
/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_password;

    ...
}
```

And I have child class:

```
/**
 * Class Parent
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="parents")
 */
class Parent extends User
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string")
     * @var int
     */
    private $_address;

    ...
}
```

How insert `Parent.user_id` after save `User`?
And are all the annotations correct?

I use `laravel-doctrine` and catch next exception:
File mapping drivers must have a valid directory path, however the given path [/var/www/app/Entities] seems to be incorrect!

Comment: Why do you use SINGLE_TABLE inheritance? please read the docs carefully http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: @DenisAlimov , I changed it, but now I catching exception, that `Parent.user_id` can't be null.